# How to play a MP4 video on the launch screen when the app loads

Tags: ios, swift

I have a MP4 video that I want to put on the launch screen. Like who when on image loads on the launch screen but now just a video. And I do know how to put a image on the launch screen but not a video any help?

Comment: @user5349223 How u accept below answer you can not give custom class to LaunchScreen then how its works perfectly for you

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a custom ViewController for "Main Interface" and use it after the LaunchScreen with use AVPlayer inside. In swift will be something like this:

```
var player: AVPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadVideo()
}

private func loadVideo() {

    //this line is important to prevent background music stop
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
    } catch { }

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("your path", ofType:"mp4")

    player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!))
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = -1

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    player?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    player?.play()
}
```

Comment: how to move to next screen after end of video

Comment: @GaneshSomani You can add an observer to AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification

Comment: However the launch screen is showed for a very short duration of time, How to you keep the launch screen for the complete duration of the video?

Comment: @AnaLlera How it is possible because u cant give custom class to LaunchScreen

Comment: @AnaLlera How this answer is acceptable it is not working and it is not possible to give custom class to LaunchScreen

Comment: I already edited my answer to make it more clear that I'm talking about a custom ViewController (Main Interface) after the Launch Screen file

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5.1**

You can create a custom ViewController for "Main Interface" and use it after the LaunchScreen with use AVPlayer inside. In swift will be something like this:

```
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
```

---

```
var player = AVPlayer()

 private func loadVideo() {
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.ambient)
    } catch { }

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Video Path", ofType:"mp4")

    player = AVPlayer(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!) as URL)
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    playerLayer.zPosition = -1

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

    player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    player.play()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**With latest syntax in swift3**

```
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AVPlayer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.loadVideo()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    private func loadVideo() {

        //this line is important to prevent background music stop
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
        } catch { }

        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Juvi Landing Page Animation", ofType:"mp4")

        let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: path!)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: filePathURL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

        playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.zPosition = -1

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)
        player.play()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a video on the launch screen, but can start a video as soon as the apple starts.
Visually, the effect can be undistinguishable.

Just add the video play call on the **viewDidLoad** method of your first view controller, and place in some control not to force the user to view it all the times the app is run. Otherwise your users will get annoyed soon.

Yom might want to adapt the first photogram of the video to your launch screen, and provide different videos for several device resolutions. Keep in mind that the various video sizes of supported by the various mobile apple devices don't exactly always match the display size of each devices.

Your mileage may vary, you will need to "rotate" your videos in such a way that it appears to be "vertical" when played in horizontal.

E.g.:

```
- (void) play{
NSString *videoName=@"video320";
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        videoName=@"vid_trailer";
        CGFloat height =self.view.frame.size.height;

        //test retina display
        if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)] == YES && [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.00) {
            // RETINA DISPLAY - you may need to add check for @3x resolutions
            videoName=@"video920";
        }

        if (height > 460.0){
            videoName=@"video1096";
        }
    } else {
        videoName=@"video768";
        self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    }
        NSString *urlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle]     pathForResource:videoName ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSLog(@"urlString=%@",urlString);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];
    if (self.videoPlayer != nil)
    {
        [self.videoPlayer stop];
        self.videoPlayer=nil;
    }
    self.videoPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    self.videoPlayer.view.frame=self.view.frame;


self.videoPlayer.fullscreen=NO;
[self.videoPlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
[self.videoPlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self.videoPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(terminateVideo:)
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
 object:nil];
for(UIView* subV in self.videoPlayer.view.subviews) {
    subV.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.videoPlayer.view];
[self.videoPlayer play];
```

}

```
- (void) terminateVideo:(id)sender{
     [self.videoPlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
     self.videoPlayer =nil;
     self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
 }
```

Comment: Thanks But I code in SWIFT do you know how to translate this? Thanks

Comment: You can use "switify" to convert Objective C to Swift: https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/code

The alternative would be recoding that in SWIFT by hand.