# Optimal approach to animating in iOS launch screen

Tags: ios, animation

I'd like to launch my app with an animated logo. From what I understand, we have access to an initial view that does not allow custom classing but allows the use of resources.

I've read this answer here for help: [How to Play a mp4 Video on the launch screen when the app loads Xcode SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33185967/how-to-play-a-mp4-video-on-the-launch-screen-when-the-app-loads-xcode-swift)

**Which approach would be better and why?**

First, I would launch with a static image of the logo:

1. Segue from the initial launch view, and animate the logo myself in Swift.
2. Segue from the initial launch view, and then use AVPlayer to play a video (or a GIF) of the logo being animated.

I want a seamless transition from what appears to be the static launch logo image to the animated logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 if your animation is short, because it's less complicated. Option 2 if the animation is long and would take too much memory otherwise.

Option 1 is pretty easy:

Im assuming you're using storyboards. So create a new view controller (call it LogoAnimationViewController or something) and set it as initial view controller in your storyboard. In it's viewDidLoad, do this:

```
UIImage *animationImage = [UIImage animatedImageNamed:@"logo-animation" duration:1];
UIImageView *animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:animationImage];
animationImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
animationImageView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));
[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    UIViewController *viewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"]; // put whatever view controller you wanna show after the animation here
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

The transition from the launch image to the initial view controller is smoothly crossfaded by default.